# Significance of number in each flag returned - SCNetworkReachabilityFlags

Tags: ios, ipad, vpn, reachability

I am trying to check if the VPN connectivity is on or off in an iPad inside an iOS app programatically. 
The below code always says that the given host in my organization is always reachable 
even though the VPN connectivity is off in the iPad. But when I printed the flag obtained using the  "SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags" api it showed a difference between VPN off and VPN on. Whenever the VPN is connected the flags print "3" and when the VPN is down the flags print "2".

My questions are

1. Can I use this flags to determine the VPN connectivity ?
2. What is the significance of these numbers ?
3. Can anyone please provide me more info on these flags ?

Following is my code:

```
bool success = false;

const char *host_name = [@"<<host name here>>"
                         cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL,
                                                                            host_name);
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
NSLog(@"success=%d",flags);
bool isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) &&
!(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
if (isAvailable) {
    NSLog(@"Host is reachable: %d", flags);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Host is unreachable");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, these flags are defined in the [SCNetworkReachability Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNetworkReachabilityFlags). As you'll see, these are bitwise flags, so "2" means only `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable` is set, whereas "3" means that both that and `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection` are set.